# Documentation or tutorial for spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Has anyone used Spring boot's spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos feature? I could not find any tutorials or documentation on the web. I am aware of the Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Atomikos + multiple database article. I want to know if it is easier to configure the same with spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos.

Any pointers to documentation or a tutorial is greatly appreciated!

I checked the Spring.io forums and found the relevant Spring Data forum [have been deactivated](http://forum.spring.io/forum/jpa-orm/751217-forum-deactivated) with new address pointing to Stack Overflow. Spring does not have any other forum where I can ask this question.

Comment: can you please give an example how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is brand new so I doubt it has much coverage on the interweb yet. There's a sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jta-atomikos, and documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jta. You should just be able to add Atomikos to your classpath, and create `DataSource` `@Beans`.

Comment: Thank you for your input Dave! I will give the examples a try.